# IDataProtector Protect and Unprotect Methods

Tags: owin, katana

With regards to implementing the IDataProtector interface, both of the interfaces methods, Protect and Unprotect both receive a byte array as a parameter.

What is actually in this byte array?  Is it encrypted data?  What format is it in?  I have not been able to find any documentation related to this other than indicating it is user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it can be whatever you want. For exaple if you are using `SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` there is

```
public string Protect(TData data)
{
    return this._encoder.Encode(this._protector.Protect(this._serializer.Serialize(data)));
}
```

So as you can see the `IDataProtector.Protect` is used on serialized object. In this case `AuthenticationTicket`